# Highstock - disable vertical indicator

Tags: javascript, line, highcharts, indicator

I try to find a way to disable this vertical line in Highstock. It behaves strange when there is a gap between two series (it doesn't follow the mouse, it's stick to the end of one serie). How can I disable it? I can't find it in API documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **crosshairs**, to disable it see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.crosshairs).